# Extracting first and second coordinates of an ordered pair

Tags: macros

I'm trying to find a way to extract coordinates from an ordered pair in TeX. See this example code.

```
documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\begin{document}

% #1 and #2 are ordered pairs
\NewDocumentCommand{\coord}{ m m }
{
#1, #2

% Ordered pairs which correspond to (a) first coordinate of first pair and second 
% coordinate of second pair, (b) second coordinate of first pair and first coordinate of 
% second pair.

(#1[1], #2[2]), (#1[2]. #2[1])
}

\coord{(1, 2)}{(3, 4)}

\end{document}
```

The expected output from `\coord{(1, 2)}{(3, 4)}` would be

```
(1, 2), (3, 4)
(1, 4), (2, 3)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because your desired syntax uses `{...}{...}`, we need to remove them first and then to read the coordinates again by \coordA macro.

```
\def\coord#1#2{\coordA#1#2}
\def\coordA(#1,#2#3)(#4,#5#6){\par(#1, #2#3), (#4, #5#6)\par(#1, #5#6), (#4, #2#3)\par}

\coord{(1, 2)}{(3, 4)}
```

The trick `#2#3)` instead only `#2)` removes the optional space before such parameter.

Comment: +1 the OP didn't seem keen on this when I suggested it before the question was posted though:-) https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/55818029#55818029 and https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/55827051#55827051

Comment: Hi @wipet. Thank you for the answer. It works, but I don't understand "The trick #2#3) instead only #2) removes the optional space before such parameter." Can you elaborate on what is going on here? In particular, what is `#3` matching? I printed it out, and it looks like `#2` is matching 2 and `#3` is matching an empty string. And how does that remove the optional space, anyway?

Comment: `#2` is unseparated parameter (no separator follows) and `#3` is separated paramater (separator `)` follows). TeX uses different algorithms when it reads separated or unseparated parameter. For unseparated: it skips optional spaces and reads one token (or token list in `{...}`). separated: it reads all tokens until separator occurs. When you are declared `#1,#2#3)` and use `\macro a, bcd)` then `a` is `#1`, optional space is skipped and `b` is `#2` and finally `cd` is `#3`. If you use `\macro a, b)` then `a` is `#1`, optional space is skipped and `b` is `#2` The `#3` is empty..

Comment: Hi wipet. I think the above comment could be usefully integrated into your answer. I could do it, if you are ok with that.